# Why does Oleg keep attacking me?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

Whenever I call Oleg to come help me out in combat, he fights the other gang just fine for a while, but when all the gang members are killed and I'm waiting for more to appear, Oleg sometimes starts attacking me (it's kind of random). I've never had this problem with my other Homies. It doesn't seem to matter what he's equipped with either. If he has nothing, he'll just slam on me, or if he has a flamethrower he'll set me on fire. I can't figure out why. Anyone know what causes this?

Comment: Do you cause team damage on him? Have you updated to the latest patch? Does this occur in missions only or only as homie? Xbox? PC? PS3?

Comment: @ColeBusby I don't generally shoot in the direction of my Homies but it can be hard to tell when things get crazy. I have The Full Package on PS3 so it's the latest version with all DLC. I haven't tried using him during a mission; I've only been using him during the Survivor missions because some are rather difficult to complete without help.

Comment: Does the same thing happen with different homies or just Oleg? Does it only occur during a moment with other giants? If it happens with just Oleg and ONLY with other giants, it could be a programming error in Oleg where they didn't separate him from the others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This actually happens with all homies: If you shoot them enough, they'll turn hostile and attack you, then leave after some time (they'll still show up the next time you call them, though).

It's just much more prevalent with Oleg because:

1. He's much larger than everyone else, so much more likely to catch a stray round;
2. He invariably charges into melee with the enemy, so any time you blow something up or set someone on fire, he'll likely take collateral damage because the big honking idiot is standing right next to the thing.